# Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>', required: 'java.lang.Class<T>

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, compiler-errors, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create AWS Lambda for endpoint that get object from data base. What I want to do is sending id(string) as request body and then I would get object. But I have some problems with that:

This is my lambda class:

```
public class GetDietLambda extends Lambda {

@Override
public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context) {
    super.handleRequest(input, context);
    try {
        String id = RequestUtil.parseRequestBody(input, String.class);
        KitchenService kitchenService = appComponent.getKitchenService();
        Diet diet = kitchenService.getDiet(id);
        return ResponseUtil.generateResponse(HttpStatus.SC_OK, diet);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return ResponseUtil.generateResponse(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());

    }


}
}
```

In this line:

```
String id = RequestUtil.parseRequestBody(input, String.class);
```

I have an error:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>', required: 'java.lang.Class<T>
```

And I really don't know what to do. Can someone help me?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163382/type-mismatch-for-class-generics

Comment: Please include your imports in the code that you have posted.

Comment: Hi, @D.Zet were you able to fix this error?